# USB Charger Voltage Specification - Transients

Tags: usb, emc, transient, compliance

Is there a specification for a USB charger that discusses whether voltage transients are acceptable, is if so, under what conditions?

Specifically, I know a USB charger needs to have a voltage of 5V +/- 5% in order to be complaint with the USB standard.  However, is it ever possible to have a voltage spike above or below that threshold and still be in compliance?  I am specifically looking at it during a radiated immunity test.

Comment: What company do you work for? Just so I know to never plug my phone into your products. Does that answer your question?

Comment: This is a hypothetical question relating to the USB specification.  I am not working on a product that exhibits this behavior.  Do you have sources?

Answer (score 0):

Look here
https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-20-specification

I would suggest starting in section 14-16, discussions of over limit